# List of numbers converted to list of strings to iterate over it. But receiving TypeError messages

Tags: python

I am trying to find the numbers that ends with 4 in a list of numbers. I tried the following code but getting an error message saying *TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str*

```
x = [12, 44, 4, 1, 6, 343, 10, 34, 12, 94, 783, 330, 896, 1, 55]
x_str = list(map(str, x))

for ele in x_str:
    if x_str[ele][-1] == "4":
        print(ele)
```

I tried to modify the code by making `x_str[ele][-1]` an integer. But now I am getting another error message saying *TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable*

```
x = [12, 44, 4, 1, 6, 343, 10, 34, 12, 94, 783, 330, 896, 1, 55]
x_str = list(map(str, x))

for ele in x_str:
    if int(x_str[ele][-1]) == 4:
        print(ele)
```

Would be really grateful to receive any help or suggestion

Comment: A `for` loop gives you the actual values from the object being iterated over.  Just use `ele` where you're currently trying to use `x_str[ele]`.

Comment: `ele` in `for ele in x_str` is string i.e. "12", "44", "4", "1" and so on in each iteration.

Comment: Typo? Presumably `x_str[ele]` is supposed to be just `ele`. `x_str` is a list of strings, and on each iteration `ele` is a particular string from that list. Indexing a _list_ (`x_str`) with a _string_ (`ele`) doesn't make sense, hence the error

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just ```ele``` works fine. My bad! I have been stuck on it for an hour!!!

Comment: No need to convert to strings.  Use the original list and check `if ele % 10 == 4:` or simple list comprehension: `print([n for n in x if n % 10 == 4])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because when you are using for loops like you did, `ele` will contain the string itself. You can't use it to access the elements of the list. You can use it directly as an string.

```
x = [12, 44, 4, 1, 6, 343, 10, 34, 12, 94, 783, 330, 896, 1, 55]
x_str = list(map(str, x))

for ele in x_str:
    if ele[-1] == "4":
        print(ele)
```

If you want to have access using indices, you can use `range` inside for loop :

```
x = [12, 44, 4, 1, 6, 343, 10, 34, 12, 94, 783, 330, 896, 1, 55]
x_str = list(map(str, x))

for i in range(len(x_str)):
    if x_str[i][-1] == "4":
        print(ele)
```

Altough there is no need to convert your int array to str array. You can find these numbers by dividing them by `10`.

```
x = [12, 44, 4, 1, 6, 343, 10, 34, 12, 94, 783, 330, 896, 1, 55]

for num in x:
    if num%10 == 4:
        print(num)
```

If you don't want to use for-loops you can find these numbers using `lambda` and `filter` :

```
x = [12, 44, 4, 1, 6, 343, 10, 34, 12, 94, 783, 330, 896, 1, 55]

result = list(filter(lambda num: num%10==4,x))
```

`result` will be a list that contains `[44, 4, 34, 94]`.

Answer (score 1):

your loop is the issue, change it to::

```
for ele in x_str:
    if ele.endswith('4'):
        print(ele)
```

Because the loop is for each, you don't need the index